# PostgreSQL reusing computation result in select query

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example using SQL I can do:

```
SELECT (a+b) as c FROM table WHERE c < 5 AND (c*c+t) > 100;
```

Is there any way to do that using Postgres?

Comment: Can't you just use:   SELECT (a+b) FROM table WHERE (a+b) < 5 AND ((a+b)*(a+b)+t) > 100;??  I understand that it would be easier the way you suggest, but I just tried and it does not work.

Comment: a+b is just example, in my case it is distance calculation using postgis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be an alternative you might use:

```
SELECT foo.c
FROM (
    SELECT (a+b) as c FROM table
) as foo
WHERE foo.c < 5 
AND (foo.c*foo.c+t) > 100
```

From a performance point of view, I think it's not an optimal solution (because of the lack of WHERE clause of *foo* subquery, hence returning all *table* records).  I don't know if Postgresql does some query optimization there.

Comment: The only reason i asked that because of performance reason, and i think that performing distance calculation several times in the same query is not good at all)

Comment: yes, postgresql will realise that `foo.c < 5` is in fact `(table.a+table.b) < 5`. if you set this up as a test and create an index on `(a+b)`, you'll see that `(a+b)<5` appears as an "Index Cond"

Comment: @YuriBarbashov probably the best way to be sure is to wrap the calculation in a function, and have it `RAISE INFO` to see how many times it gets called. You can also experiment with setting the stable vs immutable properties that way, too.

Comment: Also, try the "Explain Query" function in pgAdmin to confirm @araqnid comment

Comment: i simply tested it on 100000 records db, query time is proportional to number of function call

Comment: And i have tried your variant, but postgres reverts it back to useing several function calls)))) thats funny)

Answer (score 14):

You cannot do that. Neither in PostgreSQL nor in standard SQL. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-SELECT-LIST)

> An output column's name can be used to refer to the column's value in
>   `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` clauses, but not in the `WHERE` or `HAVING` clauses;
>   there you must write out the expression instead.

One could debate the standard in this regard. Hugh Darwen goes to great lengths doing that in [this article](https://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/HAVING-A-Blunderful-Time.html) I was recently referred to.

You can use a subquery like [Federico suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11218355/939860), or a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) like this:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT a + b AS c FROM x)
SELECT c
FROM   cte
WHERE  c < 5
AND    (c*c+t) > 100;
```

CTEs are especially useful for more complex operations or if you want to reuse the interim result in multiple (sub-)queries.

Comment: @YuriBarbashov: There are quite a few things that work "nicely" in MySQL - until they don't. :)